# jQuery UI Autocomplete JSON response question

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've done a ton of research and I still don't get how to use jQuery ui autocomplete. The auto complete does not work and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated it!

I have the following on the frontend.
1. jQuery correctly linked.
2. jQuery-ui correctly linked.
3. jQuery-ui css correctly linked.

```
<script>
$("#tags").autocomplete({
source: function(request, response){
$.post("/panel/tags.php", {data:request.term}, function(data){     
    response($.maps(data, function(item) {
    return {
        label: item.tagName,
        value: item.tagID
    }
    }))
}, "json");
},
minLength: 2,
dataType: "json",
cache: false,
focus: function(event, ui) {
return false;
},
select: function(event, ui) {
this.value = ui.item.label;
/* Do something with user_id */
return false;
}

});
</script>


<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" size="50" />
</div>
```

On the backend:

```
$query_tags = "SELECT tagID, tagName FROM DCB_Tags WHERE tagName LIKE '".$_GET['tags']."%' ORDER BY tagName ASC LIMIT 10";
$result_tags = mysql_query($query_tags)  or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());

$response = array();
$tags = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_tags)) 
{ 
$tagID=$row['tagID']; 
$tagName=$row['tagName']; 
$tags[] = array('tagID'=> $tagID, 'tagName'=> $tagName);

} 

header("content-type: text/javascript");
echo json_encode($tags);
exit();
```

Output for this is:

> [{"tagID":"1","tagName":"art"},{"tagID":"4","tagName":"art
>   shows"},{"tagID":"3","tagName":"artist"},{"tagID":"2","tagName":"design"}]

If you access the page by putting ?tag=art it correctly eliminates "design".

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are doing a `post` then trying to pick up `$_GET['tags']` on the php page. So, try using an `ajax` function and picking up `$_GET['term']` on you php page. Also, `$.maps` is not a function. I think you meant `$.map`.

And, if you want the `label` as the value of the input, then don't specify a `value` field. The autocomplete will use `label` for both if you only specify one.

jQuery autocomplete:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/panel/tags.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {term: request.term},
            success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.tagName
                       };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      /* Do something with user_id  */
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$query_tags = "SELECT tagID, tagName FROM DCB_Tags WHERE tagName LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term'])."%' ORDER BY tagName ASC LIMIT 10";
```

Link to tutorial: http://www.jensbits.com/2011/08/24/using-jquery-autocomplete-when-remote-source-json-does-not-contain-label-or-value-fields/

Comment: Awesome! Just a note: I needed a different value than the label (cust_name and cust_nbr in my case).  after "label: item.tagName" add a second line: "value: tagId".  Also, my JSON return from server included a sub-array with the actual data, my customer info is in data.cust_data. In your $.map do: "$.map(data.cust_data, function(item){".  (I am guessing I could have just use item.cust_data.cust_nbr)  Just an FYI in case others come upon this.

Answer (score 0):

I put "alert(data.length);" at the start of the success function, to check whether the data received from the server was correct. It made the jquery control fail to display anything upon receiving the data.